# rustup install stable error during download

Tags: ubuntu, rust

I install Rust with command:

```
$ curl -sSf https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup.sh | sh
```

when I run:

```
$ rustc main.rs
```

this appeared:

```
error: no default toolchain configured
```

so I run:

```
rustup install stable
```

then:

```
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
 23.2 MiB /  56.2 MiB ( 41 %)  67.2 KiB/s ETA: 503 s                error: component download failed for rust-std-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
info: caused by: could not download file from 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/2018-07-10/rust-std-1.27.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.xz' to '/home/kwebi/.rustup/downloads/d3b0d00357cfaecf85651bea6f1d72793a5a859b6b07e9613ba21285922d5d58.partial'
info: caused by: error during download
info: caused by: [56] Failure when receiving data from the peer (OpenSSL SSL_read: error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0)
```

at the first,I use the follow to install rust, the error information printed as before, there is a download error:

```
$ curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104
rustup: command failed: downloader https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/rustup-init /tmp/tmp.2EZ69sGKWR/rustup-init
```

what can I do to install rust currently and completely?

Comment: Have you tried it again, after the error occured?

Comment: Can you run `rustup default stable` ?

Comment: *could not download file* — you had a temporary network failure.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem with follows:

```
rustup update
rustup default stable
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Comment: i had an issue trying to run shell command in Docker container `docker run --rm -it mycontainer rustup default stable` returned `error: could not download file from 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256' to '...': failed to make network request: error sending request for url (https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256): error trying to connect: error:...:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1921: (unable to get local issuer certificate): ... `. running `rustup update` first solve it

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I removed curl installed through snap and reinstalled it through apt. And that solved my problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question as other answers look correct.