# rustup command failed: downloader using installation directions from the book

Tags: failed-installation, rustup

This references the installation directions in:
[https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-01-installation.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
`sudo curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.3 https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`
I get the following error:

> info: downloading installer
> curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
> rustup: command failed: downloader https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/rustup-init /tmp/tmp.Ji2OGHFaHM/rustup-init aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu

I had previously installed just enough rust to run Blake3.

At:
[rustup install stable error during download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355650/rustup-install-stable-error-during-download)
I found an unranked answer: (I added an uptick).
`rustup default stable`

That appeared to work.  In a similar question (Issue #2775)
https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2775
This similar problem occurred and the issue is marked closed, but the book has not been updated to reflect the changes.  I note that at the time I ran the original script, I had 1.9 Gb of free space in /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your curl

```
sudo apt upgrade curl
```

and then rerun the installation it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and found the fix here: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rustup-install-fails-on-ubuntu-20-10/59691/2

I solved it uninstalling curl from snap and installing it with apt

```
sudo apt install curl
```